# It´s possible to use Canvas.drawText to get value from strings XML?

Tags: android

I´m using but i have see numbers instead of string

```
 canvas.drawText(String.valueOf(R.string.game_lovers), 170, 150, paint);
```

Comment: Its in Surface to use the String where is in the Drawtext WTF duplicate

Comment: Yeah, that "sentence" doesn't really make any sense. The linked _possible_ duplicate should at least make it clear that the `R.string` value isn't the actual `String` itself. If you want more help, you need to provide more context to your issue. We're not mind readers. We don't know where the single line of code you've provided is in your project.

Comment: "but i have see numbers" -- Yes, because all values of `R.whatever` are actually integers. Definitely a duplicate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if it draws in `View` class, you may try

`canvas.drawText(getContext().getString(R.string.game_lovers), 170, 150, paint);`

Comment: This is the correct answer

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't get string from resources like that. You should do it this way:

```
@NonNull String getString(@NonNull Context cotext,@StringRes int stringResId) {
    return cotext.getString(stringResId);
}
```

Where res would be you res id `R.string.game_lovers`

Comment: You are using iphone.